# Unity Instantiated Objects not Receiving Light

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, instantiation

i'm trying to Create a character selection screen but when i'm instantiating my object in the Scene i'ts not receiving any light

my picture of the object :

[image]

my button codes :

```
public static GameObject SelectedCharacter;
public GameObject Cube;
public GameObject Capsule;

public void CubeButton()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Level1");
    SelectedCharacter = Cube;
}

public void CapsuleButton()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Level1");
    SelectedCharacter = Capsule;
}
```

my instantiator code :

```
void Awake()
{
    Instantiate (ButtonManager.SelectedCharacter, transform.position,      transform.rotation);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you instantiate the object shouldn't affect lighting. Keep in mind that in the picture the object seems to be receiving *some* light (if it were just ambient light, then it would be tinted blue based on the skybox, not yellow). Ensure the following:

- Make sure your light isn't set to the "baked" baking mode or it will only be precomputed to work with static geometry.
- The GameObject's layer isn't excluded in the light's culling mask
- The intended material is assigned correctly
- The light's intensity and direction are set up correctly
- The object isn't occluded by the scene's fog
- If you're changing scenes, make sure your light isn't destroyed in the process (or that the new scene contains an appropriate light)

I suggest a debugging exercise of creating a new prefab from a correctly-lit gameobject, swapping the two and seeing if lighting works correctly. Based on the screenshot you only have one object in the scene - ensure that other objects are lit correctly to narrow down the issue.